# OpenGL/JOGL: The light intensity and render time, are they related to the size of the model?

Tags: opengl, size, scale, jogl, light

For a JOGL application, I have a real-size model of an object. My model is a little big (it can be surrounded by a sphere of radius 3 meters). While working on this, couple of questions have puzzled my mind:

1. Does the size of the model has any effect on the render time? More precisely, if I scaled down my model by a factor of 0.01, am I going to have a faster render? (scaling down the model before importing and not using glScale)
2. Consider I'm brightening my scene with a light source which has a certain intensity. If I scale (up/down) my model, in order to obtain the same appearance, should I also scale my light intensity?

Answer (score 3):

1. Why should it? The model's vertex postions are just numbers and are processed by the graphics hardware, no matter what numbers they are. In the same way they are always transformed by the current transformation matrix, no matter if this is a scale matrix or just the identity. But it makes a difference how large your model is on the screen (or if it is even visible). Because the more pixels your model covers on screen, the more rasterization and per-fragment operations (fragment shader or fixed-function texturing) are done. But then again this difference may not have any impact on the overall performance when the rasterization and fragment processing time is outweighted by the vertex processing time (which in turn doesn't care about model size or visibility).
2. I don't understand this question. Light intensity is completely independent from model size. Of course a smaller model reacts differently to light than a larger one, but it doesn't make any difference if you prescale your model or use `glScale` do transform it at runtime.

Comment: Ragarding 2: If you scale your model and the light position together with it, the normalized distribution of illumination will stay constant. However light attenuation depends on absolute size. So you'll either have to tweak your attenuation or intensity parameters if you want to keep the absolute value distribution constant.